# Azure DevOps: How to get last build for an environment using comandline

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

As far as I can see, quite opposite to Azure DevOps GUI, [az cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines) doesn't support [environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) when working with pipelines/builds. Neither does [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), it seems.

I would like to get, as a part of another pipeline, repository version (commit) used by last successful build for a given environment. Is there a programmatically way of doing that?

Comment: Are you looking for the artifacts that used in a release pipeline? Have you checked `Releases - Get Release` api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: I forgot to mention that, to simplify build and deployment process we do not use releases, but have everything in the pipelines (build).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API or command to get the environments. You may submit a feature request here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22